# How I see boolean modifications in real time?

Tags: modifiers

I remember there was a check box "Apply immediately".
With it unchecked I could see my Boolean operations in real time on 3D viewport, but now there's no such box, and I can only see the result after apply the Bolean modifier.

how do this on version 2.93

Answer (score 1):

Boolean works just by adding the objects, the only thing that you need to do is to change the visibility of the object that you are using to create the boolean to Wireframe to see the modifier effect

[image]